# Bootstrapping of split.plot ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to get a bootstrap estimation of F in a split-plot ANOVA using R.

I have 1 within factor: `modality`, with 3 levels: (zero), (little) and (many), and 1 between factor: `task`, with 2 levels: cued and free recall. My dependent variable is the proportion of correct answers. All subjects learned the same list of words, in which modality was varied. Half of subjects had a free recall, and other half had a cued recall. Here are sample data:

```
subj       <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
                14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,
                25,26,27,28,29,30,16,1,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,16,17,
                18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
data5$subj <- as.factor(as.character(data5$subj))
task       <- rep(c("cued","free"), each=45)
modality   <- rep(c("zero","little","many","zero","little","many"), each=15)
proportion <- c(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.25,0.54,0.56,0.68,0.88,0.87,0.77,0.6,0.65,0.2,
                0.23,0.32,0.15,0.32,0.24,0.42,0.21,0.33,0.41,0.4,0.49,0.33,0.52,
                0.21,0.2,0.4,0.36,0.45,0.55,0.65,0.55,0.54,0.56,0.68,0.88,0.87,
                0.77,0.6,0.65,0.28,0.33,0.32,0.55,0.32,0.24,0.42,0.21,0.33,0.41,
                0.4,0.49,0.33,0.52,0.44,0.2,0.4,0.36,0.35,0.65,0.75,0.65,0.56,
                0.76,0.68,0.68,0.77,0.87,0.6,0.65,0.2,0.23,0.32,0.15,0.32,0.24,
                0.42,0.61,0.33,0.41,0.4,0.49,0.33,0.52,0.51,0.66,0.58,0.3)
data5 <- data.frame(subj=subj, task=task, modality=modality, proportion=proportion)
```

And this is my model:

```
anova1 <- aov(proportion~task*modality + Error(subj/modality), data=data5)
summary(anova1)
```

My question is how can I obtain a bootstrap estimation and CIs for F? I tried this code:

```
f <- function(d, i){
  d <- d[i,]
  return(aov(proportion~task+modality + Error(subj/modality), data5)
}
bootF <- boot(data5, f, R=1000)

Error in boot(data5, f, R = 1000) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

And I get that message. What is wrong?

P.S. I know that ANOVA over proportions is not a good solution. I'm writing my master thesis, where I want to compare estimates of ANOVA, logistic regression and mixed logit model.

Comment: Sorry, I m new at statexchange and also in R. What do you mean "reproducible example"? Short data or what?

Comment: I m very sorry. I m fresh at this community site, and also in R. What should I include to be more informative? I m not sure I understand how to provide reproducible example.

Comment: Dear Gung, I finaly figure it out! I ll try to add example properly.

Comment: Dear @gung, I have edited my question. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: I don't really follow the comparing ANOVA, LR & the GLMM. We know by definition that ANOVA & LR are invalid.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong, but it is very common practice in psychology. Through this work I want to encourage researchers to use logistic regression and mixed logit models.

Comment: I get an answer at another site from Sam Mancuso:http://sammancuso.com/2015/05/18/bootstrapped-anova-and-ancova-in-r/comment-page-1/#comment-8 .Should I write an answer, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Sam Mancuso helped me solve the problem. He wrote this code.

```
boot.F <- function(data, i){#bootstrap function

dataResample <- data[i, ]# resample data

anovaResult <- aov(proportion ~ task*modality + Error(subject/modality), data = dataResample) # Run ANOVA

FValues <- c(summary(anovaResult)[3][[1]][[1]]$`F value`[1:3])# Extract F-Values (task, modality, task:modality)

return(FValues)# Returns FValues
}

# Set seed for replication
set.seed(12345)

# Run bootstrap on F-Values
anovaBoot <- boot(data, boot.F, R = 1000)

# Confidence Intervals
boot.ci(anovaBoot, index = 1) # task
boot.ci(anovaBoot, index = 2) # modality
boot.ci(anovaBoot, index = 3) # task:modality
```